# How can I redirect to home when user click on back button after logout?

Tags: php, wordpress, logout, back

I was wondering how can I redirect users to my hompage after they logged out when they hit the back button, kind of like facebook does. I was playing around with some javascript but nothing seemed to work.

PS: This will be for a Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there check the [wp_logout_url($redirect_url)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url).

Comment: Its not the logout function that I need, is the redirect when the user clicks back in the browser, if I use that it works fine but then if I click back on my browser it will show me that last screen where I was, I wan't to show my home screen instead

Comment: @ javiervd if this answer was not helpful then why did you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use sessions, you can check if the user is logged in when viewing an authenticated page, and if not, send the headers to your homepage.

Comment: I already use a verification with php, and it works fine (its pretty much if (!user_is_loggedin) redirect to main page; but the problem with loggin out and going back is that the browser seems to bypass this check and just loads the previous screen, however if I attempt to do anything here like clicking a link it does redirect me to the loggin page. I've seen it work like this in almost every site, actually facebook is the only one I've found that works like that, and sadly my client wants it that way...

Comment: are you destroying the session completely?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript seems like the way to do it. Simply check if the user is logged and if not, do a redirect to the home page via a document.location = "http://my.home.page";

I guess that you have the session in PHP too so you could just do the redirect there instead of relying on Javascript.

```
header ('Location: http://your.home.page');
```

Comment: I already use a verification with php, and it works fine (its pretty much if (!user_is_loggedin) redirect to main page; but the problem with loggin out and going back is that the browser seems to bypass this check and just loads the previous screen, however if I attempt to do anything here like clicking a link it does redirect me to the loggin page. I've seen it work like this in almost every site, actually facebook is the only one I've found that works like that, and sadly my client wants it that way...

Comment: OK I see the problem. When you click back, it recovers the page from cache. You can try disabling cache. Please see this link : [link]http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17477[link] and keep in mind that some browsers might handle this awkwardly. You can also try to reverse engineer the javascript used by Facebook.